# How to configure ejabberd working with https

Tags: https, ejabberd

How to configure ejabberd with https instead of http? can any one help me with it ? i didn't understand what is certificate  "ejabberd.pem" in ejabberd?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the documentation. It is explained in listener section: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#listening-ports

Look at example configuration for port 5281.

A .pem file is a certificate file format that should include private and public key. From the definition on this site: http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/

> PEM Files: The standard format for OpenSSL and many other SSL tools.
>   This format is designed to be safe for inclusion in ascii or even
>   rich-text documents, such as emails. This means that you can simple
>   copy and paste the content of a pem file to another document and back.

Comment: Ok i got the ssl certificate. how to verify certificate is proper or not? File contain both  CA sign  certificate and Private Key. I am trying to configure https in ejjaberd but not getting connected. I user port 5281 for https and give path of certificate in ejabberd.yml. It shows an error page not found. i think i am doing some wrong config in ejabberd.yml?  please give any reference link for configure ejabberd.yml with ssl.

Comment: Now i am done with ssl certificate and my https is working in admin portal of ejabberd. I want to connect ejabberd with java smack. But getting error "Hostname verification of certificate failed. Certificate does not authenticate". please give any suggestion.